# How to Create a Loop Here? C++

Tags: c++, loops

Here is my code. I want it to ask for the name of file until it is a valid name. How will I do it? In my current code it stops after the fail.

```
void X() {
    string fileName;
    ifstream inFile;

    cout << "Enter the name of the file: " << endl;
    cin >> fileName;
    ifstream input;
    input.open(fileName);

    if (input.fail()) {
        cout << "Could not open the file " << fileName << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: The last brace is not in the code block, you need to indent it by 4 spaces.

Answer (score 1):

```
void X() 
{
  string fileName;
  ifstream inFile;
  do {
    cout << "Enter the name of the file: " << endl;
    cin >> fileName;
    ifstream input;
    input.open(fileName);
    if(input.fail())
    {
       cout<< "Could not open the file "<< fileName<< endl;
    }
  }
  while(input.fail())
}
```

should do the trick. That way, as long as the file open operation does not succeed, the code will keep on trying.

Comment: Do you mean `while (!input.fail())`?

Comment: Oops, missed that. Thanks!

Comment: The loop condition makes no sense now. It should probably be inverted so that the loop is executed until the user enters a file name that can be opened. Your first version was probably correct.

Comment: Yup. I reacted too fast. It's late here. :) @David: it is `while(input.fail())` because we want the loop to exit as soon as the file is opened, so only to loop if the `open` call failed.

Comment: @Nordin: If my answer is what you were looking for, can you accept it?